# On creating new database in sql server 2008, some tables created automatically?

Tags: sql-server

When I create any new database It automatically create some tables in new database.

Details:

I created a new database "TestDatabase" using below command

```
Create database TestDatabase
```

When I expand the Tables folder, I found that there are already some tables created automatically.

These are those tables which I was using in some other database.

Table names:
1. Employee
2. Admin
etc

How can I create new fresh database to make sure that no tables created in it?

Comment: which version of SQl server u r using?

Comment: Sql server 2008 as mentioned in question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably at some point you accidentally created these tables in the `model` database.

This is used as the template for creating new databases. Simply delete them from `model` to stop them appearing in every freshly created database.

Comment: Thanks. I have deleted the tables from model and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server uses the `model` database as the basis for new databases. Check and see if these tables exist in `model` - and if they do, delete them.
You should probably check for other objects in `model`too (stored procedures, views etc).